# Instanciar classe ou usar métodos públicos?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, método, métodos-estáticos

Ao usar um método de uma classe, existem duas abordagens: instanciar a classe e usar o método pelo objeto, ou tornar o método `public static` e chamar diretamente. Existe algum problema em usar um ou outro? Segurança, performance, etc.

Por exemplo:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
cliente.cadastrarCliente();
```

Ou tornar o método `static` e algo como:

```
Cliente.cadastrarCliente();
```

Comment: É.. eu pensei nisso, mas sempre tem aquelas "melhores práticas", as vezes "desnecessárias", tipo deixar primeira letra da classe em maiúscula. Então em questão de segurança, performance e etc, não impacta em nada?

Comment: Isto não é uma questão de opinião, é bem objetivo onde pode ou não usar.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 7):

Depende. Se você acessa algum membro de instância você não tem opção, tem que chamar o método baseado em uma instância.

Se não acessa nada da instância, ou seja, o método é apenas utilitário ao objeto e portanto pertence à classe é melhor torná-lo estático e acessar pela classe. Aí pode evitar criar uma instância só para isso. E o método estático costuma ser ligeiramente mais rápido.

Se você tiver algum analisador estático, como o [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) por exemplo, tem a indicação para você fazer isso. Por padrão se não acessa nada da instância, torne-o estático. Se acessa, verifica se não é melhor torná-lo estático e receber um parâmetro para fazer o que deseja.

Se olharmos a [classe `String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0), por exemplo, ela possui uma quantidade enorme de métodos estáticos já que muitas vezes não precisa acessar a instância em si. Mesmo esses métodos vão trabalhar com uma instância de `String`, mas pode recebê-la como parâmetro. Não precisa de acesso privilegiado ao objeto.

Há quem não goste porque em tese isso não é orientado a objeto, mas há os pragmáticos.

Há quem indique que isso prejudica a testabilidade. Na verde prejudica mais o *mock* ou alguma técnica parecida. É possível testar e na maioria das vezes nem é mais difícil.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi. No meu caso eu preciso fazer um CRUD simples em base de dados com os valores dos forms. Nesse caso torna-lo estático estaria tudo certo?

Comment: Aí eu não tenho como responder. Como eu disse, depende. Eu te dei o parâmetro. Você está procurando uma regra geral para seguir, isso não funciona, tem que analisar cada caso.

Comment: Cara, dá uma olhada nesse capítulo da [apostila da Caelum](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-csharp-orientacao-objetos/metodos-e-atributos-estaticos/). Acho que pode te ajudar a antender! :-)