# Instanciar classe com método static

Tags: c#, static

```
namespace Classes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Editora ed = new Editora();

            Program p = new Program();

            ed = p.EntradaDeDados();

            ed.InserirProvedorSql(ed);

        }

        public Editora EntradaDeDados() {
            Editora ed = new Editora();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome da editora:");
            ed.Nome = System.Console.ReadLine();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Digite o E-MAIL da editora:");
            ed.Email = System.Console.ReadLine();

            ed.DataRegistro = DateTime.Now;

            return ed;
        }
    }
}
```

A classe `Program` foi criada automaticamente junto ao método `static void Main`.
Fiz um método para a entrada de dados nessa classe. Quando fui chamar este método no método `static void Main`, precisei instanciar a classe `Program` dentro dela mesma. Achei isso bem estranho. Percebi que isso acontece quando é um método `static`. Por que o método `static` obriga a gente a instanciar a própria classe?

Eu modifiquei o método `Main` de `static` para `public`, mas deu erro na hora de executar o projeto, disse que não contém um `static Main`. Por que é obrigatório ter um método `static`? Também retirei aquele “string[] args” que não sei para que serve.

Comment: Se quiserem podem fechar ou excluir essa pergunta (não sei se tem como excluir).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem alguns erros de conceituação na pergunta e o comentário do AP na outra pergunta é importante, mas ao contrário.

> A classe Program foi criada automaticamente junto ao método `static void Main`

Aprenda programar, não aprenda o que alguma ferramenta ajuda você. O C# não cria nada, então trabalhe com essa ideia.

> Fiz um método para a entrada de dados nessa classe

Em códigos reais não costumamos fazer isso, cada um com sua responsabilidade.

> Quando fui chamar este método no método `static void Main`, precisei instanciar a classe `Program` dentro dela mesma

Na forma que foi feito precisa mesmo.

> Percebi que isso acontece quando é um método `static`. Por que o método static obriga a gente a instanciar a própria classe?

Não, o problema é ter um método que não é `static`. Métodos estáticos estão disponíveis para a aplicação, métodos de instância, que é o caso do `EntradaDeDados()`, exigem que se crie uma instância. Então a pergunta não cabe.

> Eu modifiquei o método `Main` de `static` para `public`

`public` e `static` não são relacionados, então poderia ter ambos, não precisa mudar.

O `Main()` precisa ser chamado pelo .NET, ou seja, precisa estar disponível para a aplicação sem precisar instanciar nada. Então ele precisa ser obrigatoriamente estático. O `Main()` em si não é tão especial assim, você pode determinar o ponto de entrada da aplicação, mas ele sempre tem que ser estático. O `Main()` é uma convenção interessante.

Isto tudo já foi respondido em [Por que o ponto de entrada das aplicações é um método estático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247376/101). Então tecnicamente a pergunta é uma duplicata, mas tem um pequeno detalhe que não está na pergunta que a torna interessante.

> Só não sei para que usar `static`

A pergunta correta deveria ser: por que não usar `static`?

O que você ganha em não usar `static`?

O ganho é que pode criar instâncias daquilo, pode gerar um objeto baseado naquele modelo. Na verdade não só pode, exige, afinal se um membro está disponível para a instância você só pode acessá-lo pela instância.

[Quando mais simples melhor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Criar uma instância sem necessidade não faz sentido. É verdade que em uma aplicação real este método sequer estaria ali, mas já que está, não tem porque ele não ser `static`. Isso é o simples. Mesmo no lugar certo só faria sentido em um outro contexto, teria que ser uma classe que trata da entrada de dados de editora e criada de uma forma que a instância seria mais adequada que a forma estática.

> Mas eu posso acessar métodos que não são `static` dentro do `static`, preciso fazer a instância de um objeto da classe que tem esse método

Poder, pode, mas para que?

Um dos problemas do exemplo simplificado para aprender é que ele não ensina estruturar uma aplicação. Ele é ótimo para aprender conceitos simples, pontuais, que muitos programadores ignoram e isso é pular um degrau, por isso a maioria dos programadores não conseguem programar, você está indo no caminho certo, só não ache que agora está aprendendo estruturar toda a aplicação, isso é bem mais difícil do que as pessoas acham.

Aprender o pontual primeiro e o todo depois. Só não perca de vista que enquanto está aprendendo o pontual não está estruturando corretamente. Esse é um engano comum em iniciantes, veem um exemplo e acham que aquilo é o correto quando na verdade é só uma simplificação para mostrar o ponto sendo ensinado. Nem vou entrar no mérito de que há quem não sabe fazer e tenta ensinar.

Quando fizer algo que exige uma instância aí poderemos ajudar desta forma, neste momento a solução para seu problema é tornar o método estático.

[Instanciar classe ou usar métodos públicos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177216/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não fiz o método porque era o correto a se fazer ou porque melhoraria o sistema, eu quero entender o por que das coisas. Acho que não vou entender através dessa pergunta, é melhor eu buscar o entendimento das coisas, fui meio que afobado e já quis perguntar do porquê disso e daquilo. Na verdade, havia lido algumas coisas, mas não compreendi muito bem, não sei se tenho vocação para programação. E obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Não podemos modificar a assinatura do método `Main`, pois ele é especial. Ele marca o ponto inicial e chamado automaticamente quando executamos nosso programa. Veja [mais aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/).

Métodos estáticos não nos obrigam a instanciar a própria classe.

O que acontece é que não é possível acessar membros de instancia de dentro deles, ou seja, qualquer variável ou método que não seja estático, não pode ser acessado a partir de um método estático.

O contrário é possível, membros estáticos podem ser acessados normalmente a partir de membros não estáticos.

Uma solução menos estranha seria tornar o método `EntradaDeDados()` em estático também.

```
public static Editora EntradaDeDados() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Mas eu posso acessar métodos que não são static dentro do static, preciso fazer a instância de um objeto da classe que tem esse método. Só não sei para que usar static.