# Por que é necessário instanciar uma classe em Python quando eu posso chama-la diretamente?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes

```
class People:
    def talk():
         print('hello')

p1 = People
p1.talk()
```

Qual a ***necessidade*** de ***instancia-la*** se posso chama-la ***diretamente***?

```
class People:
    def talk():
         print('hello')

People.talk()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Você não instanciou nada

Ao fazer `p1 = People`, você não criou uma instância da classe `People`. Na verdade você fez com que `p1` receba a própria classe `People`, veja:

```py
class People:
    def talk():
         print('hello')

# p1 é a própria classe People
p1 = People

print(p1 == People) # True
print(type(People)) # <class 'type'>
print(type(p1))     # <class 'type'>

# p1 é uma instância de People? Não
print(isinstance(p1, People)) # False
```

Para criar uma instância de `People`, você teria que chamar `People()` (com os parênteses), veja a diferença:

```py
# agora sim estou criando uma instância de People
p = People()

# p não é a própria classe People
print(p == People) # False
print(type(p))     # <class '__main__.People'>

# p é uma instância de People? Sim
print(isinstance(p, People)) # True
```

Por isso que no seu exemplo, `p1.talk()` é o mesmo que `People.talk()`, já que o valor de `p1` é a própria classe `People`.

---

Quanto ao fato de estar usando uma classe para este caso, se faz sentido, etc, além da maneira correta de fazer, [a outra resposta já disse tudo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/514666/112052).

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro, classes não são necessárias em alguns casos, mesmo que as pessoas usem onde não precisa.

Classes devem criar o modelo de objeto que sirva para alguma coisa útil, por isso ele precisa ser muito bem definido antes de codificar. Se for para fazer uma classe que não tenha sentido, então não precisa criar uma classe. Entenda [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101). Se não vai criar objetos não precisa de uma classe.

Em alguns casos é possível que queria algo encapsulado na classe e não no objeto, então isso é permitido. É mais ou menos raro precisar disso de forma correta (muita gente usa incorretamente). Existem casos de ter um métodos utilitários que independem do estado do objeto, aí faz sentido.

Exemplos artificiais não são úteis para apender programar, especialmente em orientação a objeto, só o caso real pode determinar o que é certo fazer. Exemplos artificiais até são úteis se forem bons exemplos para mostrar um mecanismo, mas nunca como usar adequadamente.

Esse exemplo é só um erro, é um exemplo artificial que não faz algo útil, então ele não pode ser considerado para o aprendizado.

O código define um modelo para um objeto, ele só tem um método dentro da classe, portanto não deveria ter uma classe aí. Isso estando errado, só não faça um código assim.

Se o exemplo fosse bom, resolvesse um problema real então poderíamos discutir melhor sobre o assunto. E de fato já foi feito em:

- [Conceito de classe, entidade e objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203166/101)
- [Instâncias e variáveis no C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/338603/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre variáveis de instância de classe, automáticas (locais) e de duração estática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257817/101)
- [Diferença entre "Atributo" e "Variável de Instância"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96710/101)
- [Qual a função de um método estático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101)
- [Instanciar classe ou usar métodos públicos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177216/101)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364547/101
- [Por que temos que utilizar o atributo self como argumento nos métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176543/101)

Então esse caso funciona por coincidência, porque tanto faz, não está criando algo real. Se tivesse um método de verdade, ou seja, se tivesse um método com `self`, como poderia chamar esse método passando o `self` sem criar uma instância antes? Aí temos um caso que a classe faz sentido e precisa instanciar.

De forma extremamente simplificada fazendo uma classe que faz sentido e usa o `self`:

```
class People:
    nome = ""
    def __init__(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome
    def talk(self):
         print('Meu nome é ' + self.nome)

p1 = People("joão")
p1.talk()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qWoU4r). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/adufeqvsvg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/Instance.py).

Agora que tem uma classe real tente acessar sem instanciar.